# Getting result : "undefined"

Tags: jquery, html, path

I have the following piece of code which fires on click of a button with class `undo`. Here variable `cls` gives outputs `a3`, `a2` etc. as expected, but when I use `cls` in

`var some = $("path#path"+cls_id).data("id").cls ;` ,

I get alert result as `undefined`. But when I replaced `cls` with `a3` or `a2` manually, got the result. Complete code:

```
$('body').on('click','.undo',function () { 
    var cls_id = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    var cls = $(this).attr('data-undo');
    var some = $("path#path"+cls_id).data("id").cls;
    alert(some);
});
```

HTML

```
<path id="path1" stroke="rgb(178, 34, 34)" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="M683 137 L742 217 L535 301 L513 220" data-id="{ "a1":"L33 24", "a2":"L442 89" }"></path>
```

Somebody please suggest a way to fix the issue.

Comment: You are mixup with `id` and `class` can you post your `HTML` structure ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the element as follow

```
<div class="test" data-id-cls="me"></div>
```

Then you should access it as follows

```
var some = $(".test").data("idCls");
```

**Note the "C" in cls it`s in capital**

Comment: Don't have any problem with data-id. `cls` is the one who makes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the selector `path`, because there is no element `path` defined in HTML. Since you already use an id selector `#path...`, there is also no need to further restrict the selector.

Simply using the id selector should be sufficient, e.g.

```
var some = $("#path"+cls_id).data("id").cls;
```

---

When you look at the `data-id` attribute, you will see problems with the quoting.

```
data-id="{ "a1":"L33 24", "a2":"L442 89" }"
```

When you change the enclosing double quotes to single quotes, you are one step nearer to the solution, e.g.

```
data-id='{ "a1":"L33 24", "a2":"L442 89" }'
```

This will give you the object, you are looking for. The second part is adding a `cls` attribute of course. The missing attribute is the reason, why `a1` or `a2` work, but `cls` doesn't

```
data-id='{ "a1":"L33 24", "a2":"L442 89", "cls": "some value" }'
```

---

When `cls` is not the name itself, but contains the name of the attribute, i.e. `a1` or `a2`, you must access the value with [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/1741542)

```
var some = $("#path"+cls_id).data("id")[cls];
```

or

```
var obj = $("#path"+cls_id).data("id");
var some = obj[cls];
```

See also [MDN - Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: actually I have a `path` in my html. And I have tested by removing the first `path` from `path#path`, but the result is  same.

Comment: `cls` is not a value inside `data-id`, but `cls` contains a value(eg: a1 or a2 etc.) which is substituted at the end of `var some = $("path#path"+cls_id).data("id").cls;` , which is actually not getting replaced.

Comment: The last part of the answer(bracket notation) helped. Could you please modify your answer so that I can accept it?